Why does the prerender sometimes not load the page?
I ran into the problem that the prerender does not always work. There is one page where the prerender does not always work; sometimes it just returns a piece of broken code, not even reaching the body. Application in React.

In the screenshot there are 2 identical requests to the page with userAgent=googlebot, it should process the pre-render and return the generated html page, but it does not always do this. But there is no such problem on other pages, and this page works great and passes all tests. What could be the reason? Thank you very much in advance for any help
I tried removing Antd components, this affected the loading, more elements began to load, but still the page rendering was interrupted due to something

Problems like these often occur in places where the code's behavior can vary based on an external factor (like an awaited web request done before rendering). Can you share more code?

you need backend of frontent part? on whose side might the problem be?

Anything prerendered. Most importantly, the point where prerendering breaks (if it does).
